# Tomcat 5.5 as service on Windows Server 2008 64bit

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2008, tomcat5.5

Has anybody managed to get Tomcat to run as a service on Win2008 64bit? I need it for a 3rd party component that my site relies on. It works fine otherwise, but I just can't get it to run as a service. I've tried all the googling I can, and experimented with various 64bit tomcat.exe / tomcatw.exe without success. Upgrading to Tomcat 6 didn't help either.
I'm running Java 1.5 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the latest builds. Your issue was the 64 bit procrun.exe/tomcatw.exe wasn't provided. The newer installers for Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 6 include both 32 and 64 bit and deploy the appropriate one

Answer (score 1):

1. Download apache-tomcat-6.0.30-windows-x64 version.
2. Extract to c:\Tomcat6
3. open command prompt run as Adminstrator
4. and go to Tomcat6\bin directory and run from command prompt>service install
5. Tomcat6 will install as Windows Service.
6. again go to Tomcat6\bin and open tomcat6w.exe run as administrator and modify your changes.
7. it works cool.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188180/

While the Java components of Tomcat run happily under a 64 bit JVM, the installers that build the Windows service are 32 bit executables and won't work correctly under 64 bit Windows operating systems.

Fortunately, the Tomcat team has put together 64 bit versions of these executables, although they only include them in the source distribution for each version of Tomcat. If you've already installed a copy of Tomcat, here's how to update the executables:

1) Download and extract the source distribution for your version of Tomcat from OLEX

2) Find the directory tomcat-X.X.XX-src/connectors/procrun/bin/amd64/

3) Copy the executables from the above directory into the tomcat-X.X.XX/bin, overwriting the 32 bit versions

4) Run the command service.bat install. This will install the service under the displayed name Apache Tomcat (the service name will be Tomcat5)

It worked to me! And I was looking for this solution for a while...